# Unable to combine two datacolumn expressions (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, expression, datacolumn

I have two tables: 'WBS' (which is a breakdown structure/parent-child table) and a table 'Costs'.

WBS:

wbs_id

wbs_parentid

subtotal1 : expression = sum(child(wbs_costs).price)

subtotal2 : expression = sum(child(wbs_wbs).subtotal1)

subtotal3 : expression = subtotal1+subtotal2

Costs

costs_id

wbs_id

price

I also have two relationships:

WBS_Costs (parentkey=wbs.wbs_id, childkey=costs.wbs_id)

WBS_WBS (parentkey=wbs.wbs_id, childkey=wbs.parent_id)

As you can see, subtotal1 is the sum of the costs associated to a record in the wbs table. Subtotal2 is the sum of all child records within the wbs table itself.

Both these expressions are working correctly.

But now my problem: when I try to combine these two in subtotal3, it is not working.

Anyone knows why?

Thanks!

Comment: `it is not working`, What you see in the column?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks lomed, value was dbnull and I guess the expression doesn't see that as a zero. Solved it by using ISNULL(expression,0)